# Can sever access client files in local web server creating by using python3 -m http.server 8080?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, networking, webserver

Can sever access client files in local web server creating by using python3 -m http.server 8080 ?

i tried access my phone files in my pc server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works exactly the other way around from what you are trying to do.

The python webserver is running on your PC/Server and hosting the files from the directory you are starting it from.

Another device in the network (your phone) can reach this server, for example on http://192.168.1.50:8080

This will allow you to **Download** files **To** your phone but not the other way around.
If you wish to do the opposite then you could try something like this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailsid=com.MarcosDiez.shareviahttp&hl=en&gl=US
(I have not tried this particular app)